# Display message if any field is missing data not displaying on save

Tags: asp.net, button, computer-science

I have a save button and when I click it I want it to check that all fields have data in them before saving to the sql table.

The issue is the data is saving even though one or more fields have no data in them.

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ucpdapps2;Initial Catalog=OnCallWeb;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into Dispatcher_Roles values ('" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "','" + DropDownList4.SelectedValue + "')", con);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "" && DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "" && TextBox1.Text == "")
            Label1.Text = "Fill In All Fields";
        else
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Successfully Added');", true);
            ClearAllData();
    }
```

Comment: Of course, you are executing the command before having checked for the empty fields. By the way, this code is very dangerous because concatenating strings to form an sql command text is well know as the way in which sql injection hacks are performed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert the data first, and then check if the controls are filled out?

You have to make some efforts here, since if you want code to check some values or text boxes before you insert, then you need to run and have that code BEFORE the insert, not after as you have.

Also, I would list out the actual field names you inserting to, and NOT guess or hope the order of the fields is correct.

So, code something like this would be better:

Warning: this is air code (google that term if you don't know what it means).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "" 
        && DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "" && TextBox1.Text == "")
    {
        Label1.Text = "Fill In All Fields";
    }
    else
    {
        // everything ok, now insert
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ucpdapps2;Initial Catalog=OnCallWeb;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            con.Open();
            string strSQL =
                @"Insert into Dispatcher_Roles 
                (FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3, FieldName4)
                values (@Dl1, @dl2, @dl3, @tb1, @dl4)";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dl1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dl2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@tb1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dl4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, 
            this.GetType(), 
            "script",
            "alert('Successfully Added');", true);
    }
}
```

In above:

Change the field1, field2 etc. to the actual names in the sql table.

Check and make sure that the data types match. For text/string, use Nvarchar as I did above, and if the value is a integer value, then use "int" for the sqldbtype.

Use parameter's. You note how we don't have a Hodge podge of "'" and quotes and all that jazz. Such code is VERY hard to read, and VERY hard to fix or write or maintain.

Move your connection setting OUT of that code. Don't hard code connection strings like that. (do you really think developers would type that over and over all day long? - they don't!!)

Hint:
Good developers are not really better at writing code. But they write code in such a way that it is easy to read, fix, and maintain. We write code that is "easy" to read, and "easy" to write. We not better at writing more code, we are better at writing EASY code which results in better code!

You also in web land can't use string concatenation for user inputs - it is FAR too dangerous for SQL injection. So, use parameter's as above.

While it "seems" like a bit more typing, it is in fact MUCH less.

When I typed in the first line of:

```
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dl1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

Then while looking at above, I hit ctrl-d in the editor, and it duplicates the line. So, now all I have to edit is the @dl1 (to @dl2), and you write MUCH less code then attempting to write and type in that long huge messy sql string.

As noted, due to web land and automated hacking robots etc., then all user input really needs to use parameter's.